Python Selenium search not working in a Google Maps API search box in a site
I'm trying to get all the results for the state of São Paulo, Brazil and show them in a CSV file
This is the website: https://www.portoseguro.com.br/fale-conosco/contatos/encontre-um-corretor
This is my code, the comments are in PT-BR
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Configuração do Selenium
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.maximize_window()

# Lista de municípios do estado de São Paulo (exemplo com alguns municípios)
municipios = ["São Paulo", "Campinas", "Santos", "Ribeirão Preto", "Sorocaba", "São José dos Campos", "São Bernardo do Campo"]

# URL do site da Porto Seguro
url = 'https://www.portoseguro.com.br/fale-conosco/contatos/encontre-um-corretor'
driver.get(url)

# Esperar 15 segundos para garantir que a página tenha tempo suficiente para carregar
time.sleep(5)

# Fechar o aviso de cookies
try:
    cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))
    )
    cookies_button.click()
    print("Aviso de cookies fechado.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Erro ao fechar o aviso de cookies: {e}")

# Rolar até o meio da página
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight / 2.5);")
print("Rolou até o meio da página")

# Esperar 20 segundos adicionais
time.sleep(20)

# Função para buscar corretores em um município
def buscar_corretores(municipio):
    print(f"Iniciando busca para {municipio}")
    
    # Esperar até que a caixa de busca esteja disponível e visível
    try:
        search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[6]/div/div/div[4]/input'))
        )
        print(f"Caixa de busca encontrada para {municipio}")
        
        # Limpar e inserir o município no campo de busca
        search_box.clear()
        search_box.send_keys(municipio + ", SP")
        
        # Pressionar Enter para realizar a busca
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(10)  # Espera a página carregar os resultados

        # Capturar os resultados da busca
        corretores = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.ps-map-list__item')
        print(f"{len(corretores)} corretores encontrados para {municipio}")

        for corretor in corretores:
            nome = corretor.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h2.ps-subheading').text.strip()
            endereco = corretor.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.ps-caption')[0].text.strip()  # Captura apenas o primeiro p.ps-caption com o endereço
            todos_os_corretores.append({"nome": nome, "endereco": endereco, "municipio": municipio})

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erro ao encontrar a caixa de busca ou realizar a busca: {e}")

# Lista para armazenar todos os resultados
todos_os_corretores = []

# Iterar sobre cada município e buscar corretores
for municipio in municipios:
    buscar_corretores(municipio)

# Fechar o navegador
driver.quit()

# Salvar os resultados em um arquivo CSV
with open('corretores_porto_seguro.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=["nome", "endereco", "municipio"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for corretor in todos_os_corretores:
        writer.writerow(corretor)

print(f"Total de corretores encontrados: {len(todos_os_corretores)}")

And I'm getting the following errors:
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier 0x00A48923+23283
        (No symbol) 0x00A0E934
        (No symbol) [0x00940733]
        (No symbol) [0x0098326F]
        (No symbol) [0x009834AB]
        (No symbol) [0x009BEE42]
        (No symbol) [0x009A4464]
        (No symbol) [0x009BCB8D]
        (No symbol) [0x009A41B6]
        (No symbol) [0x00978017]
        (No symbol) [0x0097890D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B3A5F3+1013699]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B43E4C+1052700]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B3D4B4+1025668]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A6EA2B+179195]
        (No symbol) [0x00A16833]
        (No symbol) [0x00A13198]
        (No symbol) [0x00A13337]
        (No symbol) [0x00A0B4BE]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76EDFCC9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779C80CE+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779C809E+238]

For some reason, Selenium is not finding the Google Maps API search bar or I'm just not improving it correctly.
